# Customizing the blank screen before splash screen and videos not playing in full screen on phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am building an app on phonegap that displays several links. A blank screen with the icon and title on the left top appears before the splash screen appears when I open the app. However I found online that it is normal in android but we can customize it. Is there any way I can customize it in phonegap and if so how?

When a user presses a link, it opens the link in an inappbrowser. Everything works accordingly on ios. However when it comes to android, if there are any videos in those links, they do not play on fullscreen but they do on ios. When I press the enlarge button, nothing happens. The video just keeps playing without enlarging on the android.

Below is my config.xml for android if it helps.

```
<preference name="orientation" value="portrait" />
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal" />

    <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true" />
    <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />

    <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true" />
    <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
    <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="false" />
    <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true" />
    <preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
    <preference name="MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction" value="true" />
    <preference name="AllowInlineMediaPlayback" value="true" />
    <preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="local" />
    <preference name="TopActivityIndicator" value="gray" />
    <preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="false" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="15" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="22" /> 

    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" /> 
    <preference name="ErrorUrl" value=""/>
    <preference name="BackgroundColor" value="0x000000"/>
    <preference name="KeepRunning" value="true"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <preference name="LoadingDialog" value=","/> 
    <preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false" />

    <gap:platform name="android" />

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/battery"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/notification"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network"/>
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"  />

    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen"  />
    <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration"  />


    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-xxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/icon-xxxhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xxxhdpi" />

    <icon src="icon.png" />

    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-potrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-potrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-potrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-potrait.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
    <gap:splash src="res/screen/windows-phone/screen-portrait.png" gap:platform="winphone" />
    <access origin="*"/>
```

I have been trying to see where the problem is for the last two weeks but in vain. Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: split it into 2 questions. That's how it is required by stackoverflow. One question - one answer

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for it?

Answer (score 7):

You could try this for the "blank screen that appears before the splash"

In the "platforms\android" folder under your project, open the `AndroidManifest.xml` and search for `android:theme` inside the `<activity>` tag that contains `android:name="MainActivity"` and change the default value (that is `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.NoActionBar"`) to `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"`. Save the file and build your project again, the grey screen should desapear.

Comment: I found the file under "platforms\android\app\src\main", got rid of the gray screen briefly shown before splash. Thanks!

Comment: Seems like the grey screen is disappeared but it got delay before the app is opened. Then I fixed this delay problem by placing the grey screen into white, but the splash screen has to be in white too.. how I did is just placing new theme styling in styles.xml