# Cordova Android set windowBackground programmatically at runtime

Tags: android, cordova

When the Cordova android app launches, **a blank screen is briefly visible** before cordova-plugin-splashscreen kicks in. I have learned that this is the **windowBackground colour** and can be changed by making a custom styles.xml and referencing it within AndroidManifest.xml though the activity's android:theme property. Example:

From AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:name="MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/CustomStyle" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
```

From styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomStyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/init_splash</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

styles.xml references another file just containing a drawable colour.

This works. It allows me to change the colour that appears before the splash screen.

However, I am now looking to allow the user to **optionally change to a dark theme**. I have already figured out how to modify cordova-plugin-splashscreen to change the splashscreen based on the user preference, but I'm having trouble **changing the windowBackground/theme programatically at runtime**.

I have tried adding the following within MainActivity.java or CordovaActivity.java:

```
setTheme(R.style.CustomDarkStyle);

getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(getResources().getIdentifier("init_splash_dark", "drawable", getPackageName()));

getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));
```

I placed these in the onCreate before super.onCreate() or setContentView(). The window background colour does indeed change, **but the initial blank screen before the splash stays at whatever colour was set in the manifest**.

**How can I change the activity/window background colour programmatically when the application is started?**

[Some have suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48273920/6276471) changing the app theme to a transparent one to prevent the blank screen entirely, but that causes a delay in opening the app. I'm fine with the blank screen, I just want to change it's colour programmatically.

As of April 22nd, I am yet to find a solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with the same name as of your project and it will extend Application not Activity. Put this code inside this class as this will be automatically initialized as soon as your application starts. It will be acting as a constructor for your application.
Hope it helps!
I have a project named "slot" so i created a class named slot like this

```
package com.xyz.slot;

import android.app.Application;

public class slot extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        setTheme(R.style.CustomDarkStyle);
        super.onCreate();

    }
}
```

But make sure there is no theme set in manifest as it will not be overridden.

Comment: I have placed a version of the following in MyAppName.java. Im getting the error: package R does not exist even when I import com.packagename.MyAppName.R. I tried this instead: getApplicationContext().setTheme(getResources().getIdentifier("AppDarkStyle", "style", getPackageName())). EDIT: This does nothing. I also tried removing android:theme from the manifest, to no avail.

Comment: @Terren Can you please share some portions of your code including your manifest

Comment: @Terren looking at you code i can only say to remove theme from activity in manifest and refactor your app class in "small letters".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188646/discussion-between-terren-and-vanshaj-daga).